# Get form control from raw element in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

Let's say I'm writing a custom attribute directive for use on Angular2 form elements. I want to be able to use my attribute like so:

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
  <input type="text" [myHighlight] formControlName="name" />
</form>
```

Inside my directive I have something like this:

```
@Directive({selector: '[myHighlight]'})
export class MyHighlightDirective {
  constructor (private el: ElementRef) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
};
```

But now let's say I want to do something on all changes to the input control. Maybe I want to randomize the color on each change.

The `HostListener('onChange')` event from the [Angular2 guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) works when the user is typing into the input box. But it doesn't get activated for `setValue` events that are called on the form control, even with `emitEvent` set to true. [The Angular docs on Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html) say that `setValue` will cause a `valueChanges` event to be emitted on the form control object. But I don't want to have to pass this in to the directive every time I use it, as that's clunky.

Is there any other way for the directive to get access to the original form control, given that it just has the element reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular DI to the rescue!

You can use the Angular Dependency Injection system to inject the FormControl attached to the host element of your directive.

```
@Directive({selector: '[myHighlight]'})
export class MyHighlightDirective {
  constructor (private el: ElementRef, private formControl: FormControl) {
    // have fun with formControl.valueChanges
    .......

  }
};
```

**Why this works:**

Angular registers directives into the injector of the element to which the directive is attached. So, when you ask for an instance of a particular directive, the first lookup will be on the host element first.
*(The same thing applies to components)*

Comment: I'm getting a `No provider for FormControl!` when I do that and I have `FormsModule` imported into my module. When I add `FormControl` to the `providers` part of my module, I get `Syntax error Can't resolve all parameters for FormControl: (?, ?, ?). at SyntaxError.BaseError`

Comment: Is your app divided into multiple NgModules?

Comment: Yes. I tried also importing my directive into the top AppModule, but it didn't take when I tried to use it, so instead I have a module which exports it, and then the module which applies it in the template is importing that module.

Comment: And which module is importing FormModule? Your AppModule, the module declaring MyHighlightDirective, the module containing the component using MyHighlightDirective or some other shared module that's just exporting?

Comment: MyHighlightDirective is importing it, and the module which has the input in its template is also importing it.

Comment: any chance you're using lazy loading?

Comment: We are using it, yes.

Comment: oops, i'm an idiot -  try importing ReactiveFormsModule instead

Comment: Both MyHighlightModule and the module with the input are importing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138677/discussion-between-snorkpete-and-a-duff).

Comment: Seems because of the specifics of my situation, using lazy loading and breaking the app by modules, this wasn't possible. But thanks for the answer and help! It seems it would be possible without the added complexity of how my app is structured.

Comment: using `FormControl` didn't work for me either but `NgControl` did, as illustrated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58343668/10046738

Answer (score 6):

Inject NgControl which is type of FormControlName

```
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({selector: '[myHighlight]'})
export class MyHighlightDirective {
  constructor (private el: ElementRef, private formControl: NgControl) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    ....
    //listen to validation status
    this.formControl.statusChanges.subscribe((state)=>{
       ...
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was

```
@ContentChild(NgModel)
public set model(model: NgModel) {
    ...
}
```

and you can access the control with `model.control`.