# Angular: updateValueAndValidity from directive

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have a directive that appends decimals, if the input value is a whole number, on blur. Below is the implementation.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, HostListener, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[price]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => PriceDirective),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class PriceDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  // ControlValueAccessor interface
  private _onChange = (_) => { };
  private _onTouched = () => { };

  @HostListener('blur', ['$event'])
  input(event) {
    !!event.target.value ? $(this.el.nativeElement).val(Number(event.target.value).toFixed(2)) : $(this.el.nativeElement).val(null);

    this._onChange(parseFloat(event.target.value));
    this._onTouched();
  }
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    !!value ? $(this.el.nativeElement).val(Number(value).toFixed(2)) : $(this.el.nativeElement).val(null);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this._onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void { this._onTouched = fn; }

}
```

Things work as expected.

But, since Angular doesn't trigger validation when the value is changed programatically, the textbox that has this directive, is not validated.

How can I enable validation in this case, by other means than passing the `control` reference as an input to the directive and calling `updateValueAndValidity` on it, or calling `updateValueAndValidity` on `input` or `blur`.

It would be great if someone suggests me a way to trigger validation from the directive itself.

Comment: Great question, I have the same problem. Upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same problem in this way.
It is my first approach.

```
  update() {

    // ...

    const el = this.el.nativeElement;
    const reg = new RegExp(this.textMaskConfig.replacement);

    el.value = this.prevStr.replace(reg, this.currentChar);

    // ...

  }
```

But It doesn't fire the validate event. So I get the `NgControl` component and used `setValue()` method.

```
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private ctrl: NgControl) {   
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDownHandler(e) {
    this.ctrl.control.setValue(value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved what I believe is the same problem.  I couldn't get validation to fire when I set the value on the nativeElement like in your example, or with a HostBinding to value like `@HostBinding('value') public value: string;`.  But I could get validation to fire when I set the value through ngModelChange like this:

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appPrice]',
})
export class PriceDirective {
    @Output()
    public ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])
    public formatANumber(value) {
        const cleanedValue = Number(value).toFixed(2);
        this.ngModelChange.emit(cleanedValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear to me what validation you want to add. As far as I understood, you want to reach input element of form from a directive and manipulate it based on some logic. I ll show you one way with rx.js and based on your validation logic, you can use corresponding operator.

in your generated directive file:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPrice]',
})

export class PriceDirective {
  // dependency injection for ElementRef has to set in the constructor
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private controlName: NgControl) {
    console.log(this.el);
    console.log('controlName', controlName);
    // this returns FormControlName (not FormControl) obj. it has name property that tells u which formCpntrol element u r on.
    // FormContolName class binds the FormControl to the "input" element. FormControlName has no direct reference to FormGroup
    // controlName is bound to input element's formGroup's FormGroup
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.controlName.control);
    // this returns the name of the formControl
    console.log(this.controlName.control.parent);
    // this.controlName.control.parent takes us to the FormGroup
    // this.controlName.control.parent returns observable. valueChanges watches all the formControls that you defined. if you have "a","b","c" formControls
    // with pipe() you can add operators to modify the value
    this.controlName.control.parent.valueChanges
      .pipe(map(({ a, b, c }) => // add Some Logic here))
      .subscribe((value) => {
        if (here is True) {
          this.el.nativeElement.classList.add('close');
        } else {
          this.el.nativeElement.classList.remove('close');
        }
      });
  }
}
```